# Adding Read-Only-permissions to a list for a Sharepoint Group using Powershell CSOM

Tags: powershell, permissions, roles, csom

I am trying to add read-only-permissions to a specific group called "Students" for a list I have created called "Quiz". I have to use PowerShell CSOM, but in every other tutorial I've been through, .NET server types have been used, which is not applicable to my code.

Code:

```
$ListName = "Quiz"
$PermissionLevel = "Read Only"
$web = $ctx.Web        

$lists = $web.Lists
$ctx.Load($lists)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
foreach($list in $lists)
{
    if($list.Title -eq $ListName)
    {
        $listId = $list.Id
    }
}
$list = $lists.GetById($listId)
$ctx.Load($list);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();

Write-Host "List:" $List.Title -foregroundcolor Green
if ($list -ne $null)
{
    $groups = $web.SiteGroups
    $ctx.Load($groups)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    foreach ($SiteGroup in $groups) {                    
        if ($SiteGroup.Title -match "Students")
        {
            write-host "Group:" $SiteGroup.Title -foregroundcolor Green
            $GroupName = $SiteGroup.Title

            $builtInRole = $ctx.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName($PermissionLevel)

            $roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleAssignment($SiteGroup)
            $roleAssignment.Add($builtInRole)

            $list.BreakRoleInheritance($True, $False)
            $list.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)
            $list.Update();
            Write-Host "Successfully added <$GroupName> to the <$ListName> list in <$site>. " -foregroundcolor Green
        }                
        else
        {
                Write-Host "No Students groups exist." -foregroundcolor Red
        }
    }
}
```

My error is in

```
$roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleAssignment($SiteGroup)
```

, where I'm recieving the error

```
Cannot find an overload for "RoleAssignment" and the argument count: "1".
```

Most tutorials use

```
$roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($SiteGroup)
```

which I CAN NOT USE.

How can I complete my code?

P.S. I know my code is a bit messy, but I've been spending too much time trying to find a solution, and my code has greatly reduced in quality over the past hours. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unnie](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/24111/unnie) on stackexchange helped me by providing the following code. I should have used `microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection` instead of `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleAssignment`.

```
# Get the list by Title and load.
$web = $ctx.Web 
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("Quiz")
$ctx.Load($list)
 # Load in list of groups on the current web.
$groups = $web.SiteGroups
$ctx.Load($groups)

$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$listTitle = $list.Title

foreach($group in $groups)
{
        if($group.Title -eq "Students")
        {
                $roleAssignment = $null 
                # Get the group and load into context to be used.
                $StudentsGrp = $groups.GetById($group.Id)
                $ctx.Load($StudentsGrp)
                $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

                # Break inheritance on the list and remove existing permissons.
                $list.BreakRoleInheritance($false, $true)

                # Get the permissions role for 'Read'
                $reader = $web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Read")

                # Create a role assignment and apply the 'read' role.
                $roleAssignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($ctx)
                $roleAssignment.Add($reader)

                # Apply the  permission roles to the list.
                $ctx.Load($list.RoleAssignments.Add($StudentsGrp, $roleAssignment))
                $list.Update()
                $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        }
}
```

This works! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I dont have sharepoint to test but you are getting the error on roleassignments because the method you are calling takes 2 arguments.

anyway you can try something along these lines:

```
$roleAssignment = New-Object microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($ctx)
$roleAssignment.Add($builtinRole)

$ctx.Load($list.RoleAssignments.Add($sitegroup, $roleAssignment))
```